# upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 but

Tags: 20.04, 20.10

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 and for a day or two it was all ok...
However yesterday when I opened my computer, at the login screen I saw the login screen of 20.04 and it says 20.04 at the bottom left. However the

```
lsb_release -d
```

command outputs

> Description:  Ubuntu 20.10

What's going on?

Comment: On which login screen? Are you using LightDM? Was the upgrade successful? Were there any interruptions?

Comment: @Kulfy I'm not sure about LightDM. I'm new to ubuntu as you can tell. But yes. There was an interruption due to power loss while upgrading. However it was working great for a couple of days

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen this happen when GNOME Display Manager acts up. Generally a reinstall of a few things can resolve the issue:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3 ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell
sudo systemctl reboot
```